# A geometry task for problem solvers (involving circle, points & sections)

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

Any help regarding how I should tackle this problem is appreciated.

We have a circle with the radius = 1. We also have dots, lets call them $P_1, P_2,.....,P_n $. So we have n numbers of dots, where $n \ge 1$.
Show that you can choose a spot (lets call this dot Q) on the circle's edge, so that $QP_1+QP_2+...+QP_n \ge n$.

Comment: I guess $P_i$ lies inside the circle for all $i=1,\dots, n$, am I right?

Comment: P can be anyware at all. It can be inside, outside, on it.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, assume the circle is the standard unit circle.

Let $V = P_1 + \cdots + P_n$.

If $V=0$, choose any point $Q$ on the circle, else choose $Q = -{\large{\frac{V}{|V|}}}$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;
&QP_1 + \cdots +QP_n\\[4pt]
=\;&|Q-P_1| + \cdots + |Q-P_n|\\[4pt]
\ge\;&|nQ - V|\\[4pt]
\ge\;&|nQ - 0|\\[4pt]
=\;&n\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: How can I show that 
\begin{align*}
\;&|Q-P_1| + \cdots + |Q-P_n|
\ge\;|nQ - V|\\
\end{align*}

Comment: @Patrik: 
$$|nQ - V|$$
$$=|nQ - (P_1 + \cdots + P_n)|$$
$$=|(Q - P_1) + \cdots + (Q - P_n)|$$
$$\le|(Q - P_1)| + \cdots + |(Q - P_n)|$$